# Notepad++ remove text between string+bracket and another bracket

Tags: text, formatting, notepad++

So, I've seen that you can remove between two characters and remove between two strings but I haven't been able to find a system that works between a string and a character.

I need to remove the numbers between the two brackets in...

```
provinces= {
        923 6862 9794 9904 11751 11846 11882
}
```

Keep in mind that these files also contains other brackets which are needed. I've looked around for a solution for this but none seem to work :/

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This one will do the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\b(provinces\s*=\s*\{)[^}]+(\})`
- Replace with: `$1$2`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b          : a word boundary
(           : start group 1
  provinces : literally "provinces"
  \s*       : 0 or more spaces
  =         : equal sign
  \s*       : 0 or more spaces
  \{        : an open curly bracket, must be escaped because it has special meaning in regex
)           : end group 1
[^}]+       : any character that is not a close curly bracket
(\})        : group 2, a close curly bracket, escaped.
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1$2        : group 1 then group 2
```

Comment: This still doesn't take into acount that there are several brackets in every file. This finds all of them rather than just between the  "provinces= {" and "}" that I'm looking for.

Comment: @JohannesWinqvist: It wasn't clear that you want to match only `provinces=....`. See my edit